# Excel Function, Search for Max wildcard (*)

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I have the following function that searches for a file paths, modified file date. However if my file has a wildcard at the end then this function returns a `12:00`.
This is because the file with the wildcard will have many options in the path and it is not sure what value to return.

How can I tell this function to grab the `max` wildcard file path name.

Ex: `*Stack/Over/Flow_*.csv* (a1)`  will return `12:00(a2)` because the actual folder will contain `*Stack/Over/Flow_1.csv*, *Stack/Over/Flow_2.csv*, *Stack/Over/Flow_3.csv.*`   . The work-around I have is just changing the file card path to a 1 , and it will return a proper value. But I would like the `max` of this wildcard.

Is it possible to return the `max` of whichever modified date is greater of each of these? Or do you recommend just changing the wildcard (*) to a 1 and using function as it is?

```
 Public Function getmodifieddateoffile(FilePath As String)

    On Error GoTo ExitWithError

    If FilePath = "" Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    If Dir(FilePath) <> "" Then
    'This creates an instance of the MS Scripting Runtime FileSystemObject class
    Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    getmodifieddateoffile = oFS.GetFile(FilePath).DateLastModified
    Else
    End If

    Exit Function
    ExitWithError:

    End Function
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will return the max time when using wildcards in the path

```
Public Function GetFileDate(strFile As String) As Date


        Dim lastDate As Date
        Dim FileName As String
        Dim FilePath As String

        FileName = Split(strFile, "\")(UBound(Split(strFile, "\")))
        FilePath = Replace(strFile, FileName, vbNullString)

        FileName = Dir(FilePath & FileName)

        Do While FileName <> vbNullString

            If lastDate < FileDateTime(FilePath & FileName) Then
                lastDate = FileDateTime(FilePath & FileName)
            End If

            FileName = Dir
        Loop

        GetFileDate = lastDate

    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all files in your folder and calculate the maximum yourself ?

Method for loop :

[Loop through files in a folder using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)

Comment: Thanks Jack, I would like to add the loop through the folder with the within my function. Some of these don't need to be looped, just the wildcard values need to be.